# Why is my iOS simulator not updating content after i change the content in App.js file in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

So, I am trying to create my first React Native App and in it here When I make changes in App.js file, it's not getting updated in Simulator even after I reload it or run the iOS simulator again. As you can see [image] in this image, I am trying to display "Hello" text in the updated screen of the simulator but no changes are displayed.

I run the simulator again and also I reloaded it but still there are chnages made. I want simulator to display updated content.

Comment: As I see, you have not saved the `App.js` file

Comment: Nope still the same. No changes reflected. This is my built in simulator in Xcode. do i need to add other simulator in it?

Answer (score 0):

Press `cmd+d` and select press enable fast refresh.

[image]